# android: The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Tags: android, json, variables

I do not find my error. Eclipse tell me: The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)
I want to access: matchdata -> goals -> goal -> goal_getter_name
The eclipse error is on this line: `JSONObject goal = openbuli.getJSONObject("goal");
I think the variable openbuli ist wrong?!
How I have to fix it?

Here ist my Code:

```
String result = "";
SONObject jArray = null;

jArray = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jArray;                 
                JSONArray openbuli = json.getJSONArray("matchdata");

                JSONObject goal = openbuli.getJSONObject("goal");
                JSONArray goals = goal.getJSONArray("goals");          

                 // loop array
                for(int i=0;i<goals.length();i++) {    
                                JSONObject e = goals.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.e("Name", e.getString("goal_getter_name").toString());
                        }
```

Here the json data:

```
$json (
|    matchdata => Array (9)
|    (
|    |    ['0'] (
|    |    |    league_saison =  "2013"
|    |    |    match_results (
|    |    |    |    match_result => Array (2)
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    ['0'] (
|    |    |    |    |    |    result_name =  "Endergebnis"
|    |    |    |    |    |    result_order_id =  "1"
|    |    |    |    |    |    points_team1 =  "3"
|    |    |    |    |    |    result_type_name =  "nach 90 Minuten"
|    |    |    |    |    |    points_team2 =  "1"
|    |    |    |    |    |    result_type_id =  "2"
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    )
|    |    |    goals (
|    |    |    |    goal => Array (4)
|    |    |    |    (
|    |    |    |    |    ['0'] (
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_match_minute =  "16"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_getter_id =  "5112"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_id =  "21118"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_getter_name =  "Mario Mandzukic"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_mach_id =  "23711"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_penalty =  FALSE
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_score_team1 =  "2"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_own_goal =  FALSE
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_score_team2 =  "0"
|    |    |    |    |    |    goal_overtime =  FALSE
|    |    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    |    )
|    |    |    )
|    |    )
```

Comment: You can't do this `openbuli.getJSONObject("goal");` you have to give that method an index of the array. As example: `openbuli.getJSONObject(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change `openbuli.getJSONObject("goal");` to openbuli.getJSONObject(0);
and add getJSONObject("goals") to get the object goals from the first place in the array

```
String result = "";
SONObject jArray = null;

jArray = new JSONObject(result);

                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) jArray;                 
                JSONArray openbuli = json.getJSONArray("matchdata");

                JSONObject goal = openbuli.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONArray goals = goal.getJSONObject("goals").getJSONArray("goal");          

                 // loop array
                for(int i=0;i<goals.length();i++) {    
                                JSONObject e = goals.getJSONObject(i);
                                Log.e("Name", e.getString("goal_getter_name").toString());
                        }
```