# Use getJSONObject(int)

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to parse some JSON. Here is the code. [frc-manual.usfirst.org/a/GetAllItems/ManualID=3](http://frc-manual.usfirst.org/a/GetAllItems/ManualID=3) I have been trying for several hours to get it work but every example I have seen online uses getJSONObject(int) but I can only use getJSONObject(String). This is making impossible. Am I overlooking something?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

public class JSON {
   private String html = "html";
   private String version = "version";
   private String pageString = null;
   private String urlString = "http://frc-manual.usfirst.org/a/GetAllItems/ManualID=3";

   public volatile boolean parsingComplete = true;
   public JSON(String page){
      this.pageString = page;
   }
   public String getHTML(){
      return html;
   }
   public String getVersion(){
      return version;
   }

   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
   public void readAndParseJSON(String in) {
      try {
         JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);

         JSONObject head = reader.getJSONObject("data").getJSONObject("SubChapter").getJSONObject("3").getJSONObject("children").getJSONObject(pageString);
         if(head != null){
             html = head.getString("item_content_text");
             html = html + head.length();
             for(int i = 0; i < head.length();i++){
                 JSONObject children = head.getJSONObject(i);
                 if(children != null){
                     html = html + children.getString("item_content_text");
                 }

             } 
         }

         //html = html + listFromJsonSorted(head.getJSONObject("children"));





         JSONObject main  = reader.getJSONObject("data");
         version = main.getString("LatestManualUpdate");

         parsingComplete = false;



        } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
        }

   }
   public void fetchJSON(){
      Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
         try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
         InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();

      String data = convertStreamToString(stream);

      readAndParseJSON(data);
         stream.close();

         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         }
      });

       thread.start();      
   }
   static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
      java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
      return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are seeing in this example is a JSONArray.

```
JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("array");
JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
```

In your case, i don't see any array in this JSON, **head** in your code is a JSONObject. To get the item_content_text you just need `head.getString("item_content_text");`

You can do this to get all childrens in your JSON:

```
html = head.getString("item_content_text");
JSONObject children = head;
while (children.containsKey("children")) {
   children = children.getJSONObject("children");
   html += children.getString("item_content_text");
}
```

Comment: yeah but I also need that in children nodes

Comment: but you already getting the children node in your code, i don't see more childrens in the JSON you posted as example

Comment: I think i understand your problem, you can have an object, that have a children, that maybe have a children, an so on. So you can do this. JSONObject children = head.getJSONObject("children"); if (children != null) concat

Answer (score 0):

You are only able to use `getJSONObject(String)` not `getJSONObject(int)` because the method only takes String.. Check [documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)..

The reason that is the because the keys in json are always strings only.. [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19840791/1114536)

I think you are looking to retrieve an int value from the json but you got confused.. The way to do that would be `getInt("key_name")` if the json indeed has a key with int value..

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, just that I think your "head" variable should have a return type of JSONArray instead of JSONObject.

I have this code running in my program -

```
    //response = some http response
    final JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
    final JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("repeatedStuff"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    Assert.assertEquals(2, array.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        final JSONObject element = array.getJSONObject(i);
        //do something
    }
```

Also you may refer this link to see what they are doing - [android: The method getJSONObject(int) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334947/android-the-method-getjsonobjectint-in-the-type-jsonarray-is-not-applicable-f)

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: It's wanting me to change JSONArray back to JSONObject

Comment: did you try type casting to (JSONArray) from Object?

Comment: To answer your initial question - yes its possible, if you are looping across with JSONObjects made of JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

You have used **JSONObject** everywhere in your code. Thus you are only able to pass string parameter in getJSONObject().
I suggest you you change it to **JSONArray** and then you will be able to pass int parameter in getJSONObject().